# Convert a series of strings into list in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape Wikipedia as a project to learn a bit of python 3. I've managed to get the links from a page:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
html_code = urllib.request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists_of_airports_by_country').read().decode()
souped_code = BeautifulSoup(html_code, "html.parser")
for element in souped_code.find_all("a"):
    dest_links = element.get('href')
    print(dest_links)
```

but I just get a series of strings I'd like to work with (such as in a list so can use indexes and only keep the "List_of_airports_in_" links) and filter, open, iterate over, etc. them, but I just can't wrap my head around how to achieve this as it seems to produce a series of strings.

Any insights will be much appreciated!

Comment: You create an empty list before the `for` loop (e.g. `links = []`) and then append the `dest_links` to it inside the for loop (e.g. `links.append(element.get("href"))`).

Comment: Gosh, can't believe it was so simple yet I couldn't put my finger on it, thank you very much Niklas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define an empty list and add links to it:

```
links = []

for element in souped_code.find_all("a"):
    links.append(element.get('href'))

print(links)
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
links = [element.get('href') for element in souped_code.find_all("a")]
```

Comment: спасиБо  Alexandra!!